# Would it be possible to use upcoming Intel's GPUs in desktops with amd CPU?

Tags: intel-graphics

I'm about to build a PC with amd CPU. Now I came to know next year Intel Arc GPU will be available.

Will they be similar to NVIDIA/AMD GPUs, in terms of fitting of slots on motherboard? I mean will they fit in the amd motherboard? Any reference about this?

Comment: Intel has worked on a GPU before, it was leaked back then too, but the product never came out. After that experiment, Intel baked graphics into upcoming CPU's and there is speculation that the leaked GPU was only a testboard. If the same is happening again, then its possible that GPU is actually an APU in the making, but this time it seems more true that it is going to be an actual dedicated GPU.

Comment: The Intel plans I am aware of for their GPU are only going to allow system builders (OEMs) to sell complete machines with their GPU.  Consumers won't be able to purchase them off the store shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel renders of the card, and "leaked images" of a so-called reference card depict a pci-e interface so "yes."

As far as the cards being motherboard chipset agnostic, I think it would be economic suicide for the product line to only work with intel-based boards, so I assume they will work.

They may have driver issues early on, but Intel has had for many years (IIRC) the largest GPU market, so I doubt there will be any show-stoppingly-bad driver-based problems.

Comment: Nvidia has the largest market share for discrete GPU sales. Look at [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/jpr-gpu-shipments-in-q1-2021-hit-119-million-units) as an example link. Intel [leads](https://www.techspot.com/news/90980-gpu-shipments-jumped-42-q2-amd-market-share.html) in integrated GPUs but this doesn't seem like what the OP is asking about.

Comment: In the past Intel GPU was leaked before. Linus Techtips got their hands on that GPU which turned out to be a testboard for making GPU functions inside a CPU, aka APU. If the same is true now, then the answer is no, but it seems intel is releasing actual graphics cards as of 2021. See also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-OImEmqKUc

Comment: @doneal24 Might not have been clear, but I was referring to Intel GPU drivers being "mature" and that Intel have experience with graphics drivers. I expect these new pci-e devices are not a complete reinvention. They *probably* won't be having massive issues or graphic extension support problems like e.g. PowerVR had in the quake 2 days

Comment: @LPChip all those shown in the video are integrated graphics right?

Comment: Their official Arc page mentions "add-in cards" in text, but no image

Comment: @Vikas yes, with the exception of the first and last.